# How can I decipher the Activation Policy Details for an iPhone

Tags: iphone, tethering

I'd like to decipher the  Activation Policy Details for an iPhone such as these:

•   Activation Policy Description: UK Reseller Flex Policy 
•   Initial activation policy ID: 399
•   Applied Activation Policy ID:
•   Applied Activation Policy
•   Next Tether Policy ID: 399
•   Next Tether Activation Policy Description: UK Reseller Flex Policy
•   First Unbrick Date:
•   Last Unbrick Date:
•   Unbricked: false
•   Unlocked: false

Finding what these mean one by one is proving painstaking.  I wonder if anyone could take a bit of an effort to explain them to me or advice some online resource explaining this.

You can get if from sites such as [imei.info](http://imei.info).  Apple providers also get it from GSX.  It's 100% reliable.
This one is in imei.info that they use as an example.  The explanations in this website are insufficient though.

[image: screenshot]